# Express: How to protect multiple routes with JSON web token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, json-web-token

I'm really just looking for a way to clean up my code here. I have several routes like this, note that each route individually goes through the JSON web token verification process.

```
router.route('/some-route').post((req, res) => {
  jwt.verify(req.body.token, secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    // do something
    res.json({ some: 'response data' });
  });
});

router.route('/some-other-route').post((req, res) => {
  jwt.verify(req.body.token, secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    // do something else
    res.json({ some: 'response data' });
  });
});
```

Is there some other way? Some of my routes are approaching callback-hell levels of nesting, so it would be nice to eliminate this from every route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you can tell the router to `use` the function as middleware. The function will be called for every route in `router`.

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.body.token)
    return res.json({ message: 'Missing token.' });

  jwt.verify(req.body.token, secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
    // do something else
    req.decoded = decoded
    next();
  });
});
```

Comment: Is it still possible to pass my "decoded" param into the route?

Comment: Ah yeah you can do `req.decoded = decoded` before `next()`. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that any routes above the middleware will not use it, and any below the middleware will?

Comment: Yes that sounds correct. Should be easy to test anyhow

Comment: Thanks again, this trimmed about 40 lines of code for me!